# Ubuntu 20 - CPU threads hit 100% - network drops completely until rebooted

Tags: networking, 20.04, cpu, crash, amdgpu

This has been plaguing me since Ubuntu 18.04. I have a desktop machine running Ubuntu server 20. I use it for jellyfin and a few other items. I have a problem in that whenever the CPU hits 100% on all threads, the network drops completely and does not come back until a reboot.

I've tried googling the issue a few times and haven't come up with anything to try. I have no idea where to even start with trying to fix this issue, but it's making me pull my hair out.

The system is an ASUS Prime PRIME B350-PLUS with an AMD Ryzen 5 1500X and 16 gigs of G.Skill 2400 memory.

The CPU and memory have both been changed since this issue started (upgraded from an old computer) and the issue has persisted. Any suggestions on where I could even start with troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated. It's affecting my ability to transcode among other things.

This is occurring whenever CPU usage hits 100% no matter what is using the cores.

Requested additional information:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
5220
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4.7Gi       156Mi       6.0Mi        10Gi        10Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi        26Mi       4.0Gi
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 5407
       date: 12/31/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 26
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_A1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-8GTZR
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: F4-2400C15-8GTZR
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 28
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 29
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 2a
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Bios has been updated to latest version and the issue persists.

Running stress -c 8 causes the network to drop out after ~15 seconds. The network does not come back up without a reboot.

Comment: Please look at the System Monitor, Processes tab and click on Memory so that the little arrow is pointing down (when you encounter this problem). Take a screenshot and edit it into your post.

Comment: I don't have a desktop installed as it's just being used as a server. Is htop sorted by memory acceptable?

I'll grab a screenshot and attach it once it occurs again.

Comment: This link (https://www.fosslinux.com/18444/how-to-use-htop-command-to-monitor-system-processes-in-real-time.htm) should help with htop. You can then track down whatever is hogging the CPU.

Comment: The transcode is hogging the CPU, that's not the issue, the dropping of the network when the CPU usage hits 100% is the issue.

[htop](https://i.imgur.com/OqZHVGO.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the requested information. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the bios (I realized after posting it wasn't up to date), I'm hoping that will correct the issue. I'll have a watch today and see if it has. I'll update the original post if it does in fact correct the issue.

Comment: @heynnema unfortunately the new bios hasn't fixed the issue. Running a quick stress -c 8 (to put stress on all cores) results in the network being dropped after ~10-15 seconds and not come back until a reboot.

Comment: Are there any clues in /var/log/syslog*? Show me `top` full screen. Is your CPU or memory overclocked? Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS PRIME B350-PLUS

You have BIOS version 5220.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 5407, dated 1/15/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction enough to find the issue. I ran Prime95 for a few hours and it crashed. I then figured it was the motherboard, processor or power supply (I ran prime without memory tests), and found it was a voltage issue caused by a bad power supply. The CPU wasn't getting enough power under load, causing a crash. 

I've swapped the PSU and have run prime for a while now without any issues. Thank you for all of the help @heynnema

Comment: @Taubin Good job!